# To get The model Matrix in openGL

Tags: opengl

I know that is noway to get model matrix by commands in openGL. but my app's request need to use this matrix.

Comment: Well, the whole fixed function matrix stack has been deprecated anyway. Nowadays you're supposed to take of all the matrices yourself.

Comment: I don't see any question here...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a way of getting it:

```
GLdouble modelview[16];

glGetDoublev( GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview );
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This may work, but be careful that this is technically the modelView matrix, not the model matrix. Some rendering techniques need them separated, in which case you'll have to compute it yourself.

Comment: thanks, but it got the modelview matrix, not the model matrix i needed